# Autoload language codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization, codeigniter-2

making a multi-language site with codeginiter. I have created two folders. One for french language files and one for english. When I go to autoload the languages (English and French) as such

```
($autoload['language'] = array('en', 'fr');)
```

I get an error "Unable to load the requested language file: language/english/fr_lang.php"

How can I get it to look in the proper folder?

Thanks

Comment: take look at this http://www.neonatis.com/en/gjvlangextractor/screenshots

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$config['language']
```

is the default folder used for loading language files, which is why your

```
fr_lang.php
```

is loaded from there.

Either change the value of:

```
$config['language']
```

when needed, like:

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'value');
```

(Remember this has to be done before the languages load, so you would use a hook for that http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html.)

Or else, load your language files on the fly:

```
$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');
```

You should definitely check out the core classes to get a better understanding of how things work. You can browse the code easily here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter
For instance, the languages are loaded with this class: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Lang.php

If you need any more help, let me know.