# PyroCMS accessing a module controller inside system routes file

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I tried accessing a module controller in the $route['default_controller'] setting in routes.php but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I have been getting this error a lot lately and don't understand entirely what exactly it means. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Below is my routes statement:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'contractors/routes/mainDisplay';
```

Comment: Exactly what has the default route to do with your error? See similar error at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316120/autoload-language-codeigniter

Comment: Post the filepath of the controller and the method you are requesting. It's normaly just because they are not matched correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error is about the language file not the routing. Apparently you have loaded a lang file in you module but pyrocms can't find the file. make sure that the language file is placed correctly and check the filename  which should be `contractors_lang.php`.

do you have this file?

```
../modules/contractors/language/english/contractors_lang.php
```

if not, make one.